# Interactive chart - Move a line to the position I need - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget, python-interactive

I need to create interactive chart, on which a line can be slided right/left on x axis while saving new values.

Illustration:
I have the right red line in the A position but want to move it to B position (orange line) manually and then save position B to a list.
[what i need to do with a chart picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61P8z.jpg)

I was looking at ipywidgets like the code below, but, for now, it does not seem to be helpful for my task, does it?:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual 
import ipywidgets as widgets

def f(x):
    plt.plot(np.arange(0,10), x*np.arange(0,10))
    plt.ylim(-30,30)
    
interact(f, x=10)
```

Please advise

Comment: Maybe try `pl.axvline(x)` instead of `plt.plot(...)`?

Comment: Thanks, but the widget with pl.axvline(x) works not as click on chart but as a slider out of the chart . I will need to adjust a long list of values, so sliders for each value does not suit.